# How to have a dynamic slug and rendering the archive-{post_type}.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, archives, custom-post-type-archives

So I have a Custom Post Type named network and Custom Taxonomy name company_category. Everything is all good until I can't render http://localhost/digitalhxstaging/company. Both Company Category and Company are all good except for archive-network.php. I tried removing the dynamic slug and its working but now my company category and company post is not showing its correct link. Please help me. I hope this makes sense. Below is the code with post link function.

```
public function company_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Companies', 'companies', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Company', 'company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Companies', 'companies', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Company', 'company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Company', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Companies', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Companys', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Companys:', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No companies found.', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No companies found in Trash.', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'Company Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'archives'              => _x( 'Company archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into company', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this company', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter companies list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Companies list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'dhx-portal' ),
            'items_list'            => _x( 'Companies list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'taxonomies'         => array('company_category'),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'menu_position'      => 5,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-building',
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'company/%company_category%', 'with_front' => false ),
            'query_var'          => true,
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => true,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'author', 'custom-fields' )
        );

        register_post_type( 'network', $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    /**
     * Company custom taxonomy
     * @since    0.1.0
     * @access   public
     */
    public function company_taxonomy() {

        $labels = array(
             'name' => __('Company Categories', 'dhx-portal'),
             'singular_name' => __('Category', 'dhx-portal'),
             'search_items' => __('Search Categories', 'dhx-portal'),
             'all_items' => __('All Categories', 'dhx-portal'),
             'parent_item' => __('Parent', 'dhx-portal'),
             'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent:', 'dhx-portal'),
             'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', 'dhx-portal'),
             'update_item' => __('Update Category', 'dhx-portal'),
             'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', 'dhx-portal'),
             'new_item_name' => __('New Category', 'dhx-portal'),
             'menu_name' => __('Categories', 'dhx-portal'),
        );

        $args = array(
             'hierarchical' => true,
             'labels' => $labels,
             'show_ui' => true,
             'show_admin_column' => true,
             'query_var' => true,
             'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'company', 'with_front' => false ),
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'company_category', array( 'company_category' ), $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    /**
     * Company custom permalink
     * @since    0.1.0
     * @access   public
     */
    public function company_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
        $post = get_post($id);  
        if ( is_object( $post ) ){
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'company_category' );
            if( $terms ){
                return str_replace( '%company_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
            }
        }
        return $post_link;  
    }
```

Here is the correct URL which is working

[image: enter Here is the correct URL which is working]

Let me know what you think. I just need http://localhost/digitalhxstaging/company to work

Comment: So you can get your company and categories working the way you want, right? But then archive-network.php doesn't render. Can you show the network custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your Permalinks (Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks). Just make a change, save and it should pick up your rewrite change. I've made this mistake a million times, you adjust a thing and forget this is needed.

Comment: Already done that nothing happened

Comment: Hmm. Okay, will ask some clarifying questions up on the question so others will see it.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so the solution was just adding this code to the `$args`

```
'has_archive' => 'companies',
```

Comment: Thanks! @nmr for sharing